# jquery get input value to retrieve matching array values to populate hidden inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, extract

Looking for some guidance on a form being used to extract lat/long values that are stored in an array. Code example is incomplete (sorry), just in the rough stages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$document.ready(function(){
    var geoCity = [
        { 'Toronto', '43.6532', '-79.3831'},
        { 'Vancouver', '49.2612', '-123.1139'},
        { 'Calgary', '51.04532', '-114.0581'}
    ];
});
</script>
```

When an input is entered for city field (actually uses bootstrap's typeahead on actual form), the entered value (before submission of form), needs to be used to search the arrays and extract the matching lat/long values and enter them into their respective hidden input fields.

```
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude" value="" />
```

Hoping that someone can steer me in the right direction for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, change the data structure. Then correlate input values to object keys

```
$(function () {
    var geoCity = {
        'Toronto': {
            'lat': '43.6532',
            'lon': '-79.3831'
        },

        'Vancouver': {
            'lat': '49.2612',
            'lon': '-123.1139'
        },

        'Calgary': {
            'lat': '51.04532',
            'lon': '-114.0581'
        }
    };

    $('#button').click(function () {
        var lat, lon, city = $('#city').val();
        if (city) {
            lat = geoCity[city].lat;
            lon = geoCity[city].lon;
            $('#latitude').val(lat);
            $('#longitude').val(lon);
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57PUL/1/)

Comment: Thx Jeffman, same question I posed above...would you change anything with the geoCity array values if there were 90+ cities to be referenced?

Comment: Not much. They look cumbersome because of all the space, but that can be removed. If you put the keys and values in "double" quotes, then it will be in JSON format. That would facilitate creation of the objects in PHP or some other server environment.

Comment: Thanks Jeffman, this will work out well. I've adapted the final to a combination of your answer and Chandu's as well. Using the blur function, but also setting the lat/long to empty if there's no entered for city.

Here's the final fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/swdmedia/ZYYYu/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the structure of the geoCities object as mentioned below:

```
$(function () {
    var geoCity = [{
        'city': 'Toronto',
        'location': ['43.6532', '-79.3831']
    }, {
        'city': 'Vancouver',
        'location': ['49.2612', '-123.1139']
    }, {
        'city': 'Calgary',
        'location': ['51.04532', '-114.0581']
    }];

    $("#city").blur(function () {
        $("#latitude").val("");
        $("#longitude").val("");
        var curCity = $("#city").val();
        var location = $.map(geoCity, function (itm) {
            if (itm.city === curCity) 
                return itm.location; 
        });
        if(location) {
            $("#latitude").val(location[0]);
            $("#longitude").val(location[1]);
        }
    });
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BJwhu/

You can `$("#city").closest("form").submit` instead of `$("#city").blur`.

Comment: Thx Chandu, would you change anything with the geoCity array values if there were 90+ cities to be referenced?